# I can't open the project I started in Docker, how can I solve it?

Tags: docker

I created my docker files and ran it with the apple chip. But even though I see that it works, it does not open when I click on the website

In addition, I would like to ask the following, I wanted to add vue into this yml file, but I could not find how to do it, vue2 version.

yml content

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: laravel-app
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=edanisman
      - DB_USERNAME=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=
      - PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS=0
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=edanisman
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootpassword

    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db-data:
```

I deleted the docker, reinstalled it, did purne but again it did nothing. I am also attaching a screenshot of the results.

https://i.hizliresim.com/escmc8a.png

https://i.hizliresim.com/hzjbpc8.png

It says 8080 in one of the pictures, I changed it to try it

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual output or errors from running the setup, as plain text, directly in the question?  You mention a Vue component; how have you tried to include that in this Docker setup?